# how to fill an SD card with zeros?

Tags: command-line, sd-card, secure-erase

I probably have a corrupted SD card. And I'd like to fill it with zeros, 100%.
So what commands should I type, assuming the device is `/dev/sdc`?

Comment: mkusb has an option to zero an SD card, much safer than running dd. see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Wipe_the_whole_device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where `dd` and `/dev/zero` can save the day:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Use `dd`:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=4096
   ```

That'll zero it out ... in more ways than one.

---

#### How Does This Work?

`dd` is an incredibly versatile means to convert and copy a file. [The documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/dd.1.html) contains a full list of the operands that are available, but I'll just focus on the items in the command above, one element at a time.

| Command / Operand | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `dd` | The command |
| `if` | "In File" The source data to be converted and copied |
| `of` | "Out File" The destination location for the converted data |
| `bs` | "Block Size" The number of bytes to read/write at a time |

Reading `/dev/zero` will result in an endless series of zeroes. There are a number of alternatives that people might reach for if a zero is either unnecessary or not ideal, such as `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` which are random number generators.

The `/dev/sdc` location is a storage device. If there is a number after the final letter, such as `/dev/sdc1`, then it is a distinct partition on that storage device. By writing to `/dev/sdc` rather than `/dev/sdc1` you are telling `dd` to essentially scrub the storage medium of its superblock and all media descriptors, effectively eliminating any partitions that might have existed on the device.

So, putting this all together, the command above tells the computer to do this:

Using `dd` ...

1. Read an endless series of zeroes from `/dev/zero`
2. Write it directly to the device located at `/dev/sdc`
3. Write in blocks of 4096 bytes at a time

And, of course, there is no "undo". Once this process starts, it will go until either you cancel the operation with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or the destination device runs out of space.

#### A Slight Aside

I generally run this command on all new storage devices when I first buy them. It allows me to completely scrub anything that might already exist on the drive while also testing write speed and looking for bad blocks. Twice I have found problems with USB sticks by doing this, and I was able to exchange them with the seller for properly working ones without any trouble after showing the results of the `dd` and subsequent disk checks. It is a very handy utility but, be warned, it will never ask "Are you sure?" before obliterating a partition, and there is no undo. If you make a mistake, you need to have good, recent backups ready.

And you should always have good, recent backups ready anyway

I hope this answers your question ... and then some.

Comment: Would this make every single bit into a zero? I really wanna wipe everything.

Comment: Yep. It'll completely eliminate the partitions and everything. Once this is done it will be pretty much impossible for anyone to extract whatever data you once had on the device.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how this command works and the meaning of this?

Comment: Also, does this method provide a similar output to the one shown [here](https://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=16716)?
If so, how similar would it be?